# Why this code is not showing output for n around 10^5

Tags: c++

I have the following code used to calculate primes of the form x^2+ny^2 whihc are not exceeding N. This code runs fine when N is around 80000 but when N is around 10^5 the code breaks down. Why this happens and how to fix this ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

const int N = 100000; //Change N in this line

using namespace std;
typedef long long int ll;
bool isprime[N] = {};
bool zprime[N] = {};
vector<int> primes;
vector<int> zprimes;
void calcprime(){
    for (int i = 2; i < N; i+=1){isprime[i] = true;}
    for (int i = 2; i < N; i+=1){
        if (isprime[i]){
            primes.push_back(i);
            for (int j = 2; i*j < N; j+=1){
                isprime[i*j] = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
void zcalc(){
    int sqrt = 0; for (int i = 0; i < N; i+=1){if(i*i >= N){break;} sqrt = i;}
    for (int i = 0; i <= sqrt; i +=1){
        for (int j = 0; j <= sqrt; j+=1){
            ll q = (i*i)+(j*j);
            if (isprime[q] && !zprime[q] && (q < N)){
                    zprimes.push_back(q);
                    zprime[q] = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
int main(){
   calcprime();
   zcalc();
   cout<<zprimes.size();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `(i*i)+(j*j)` is an int.

Comment: What is `sizeof(int)` on your platform?

Comment: Welcome to C++. One of the first things you should read about is how to effectively use Standard Library containers like [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of doing C-style arrays with `isprime[N]`. You're already using vectors for some array-type structures. Why not all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Why the code breaks

**Out of bounds access.** This code breaks because you're doing out of bounds memory accesses on this line here:

```
    if (isprime[q] && !zprime[q] && (q < N)) {
```

If `q` is bigger than `N`, you're accessing memory that technically doesn't belong to you. This invokes undefined behavior, which causes the code to break if `N` is big enough.

If we change the order so that it checks that `q < N` before doing the other checks, we don't have this problem:

```
    // Does check first
    if((q < N) && isprime[q] && !zprime[q]) {
```

It's not recommended to have very large c-arrays as global variables. It can cause problems and increase executable size.

**(Potentially) very large global arrays.** You define `isprime` and `zprime` as c-arrays:

```
bool isprime[N] = {};
bool zprime[N] = {};
```

This could cause problems down the line for very big values of `N`, because `c-arrays` allocate memory statically.

If you change `isprime` and `zprime` to be vectors, the program compiles and runs even for values of `N` greater than ten million. This is because using `vector` makes the allocation dynamic, and the heap is a better place to store large amounts of data.

```
std::vector<bool> isprime(N);
std::vector<bool> zprime(N);
```

#### Updated code

Here's the fully updated code! I also made `i` and `j` to be `long long` values, so you don't have to worry about integer overflow, and I used the standard library `sqrt` function to compute the `sqrt` of N.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

typedef long long int ll;

constexpr long long N = 10000000; //Change N in this line
std::vector<bool> isprime(N);
std::vector<bool> zprime(N); 
vector<int> primes;
vector<int> zprimes;

void calcprime() {
    isprime[0] = false;
    isprime[1] = false;
    for (ll i = 2; i < N; i+=1) {
        isprime[i] = true;
    }
    for (ll i = 2; i < N; i+=1) {
        if (isprime[i]) {
            primes.push_back(i);
            for (ll j = 2; i*j < N; j+=1){
                isprime[i*j] = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
void zcalc(){
    ll sqrtN = sqrt(N); 
    for (ll i = 0; i <= sqrtN; i++) {
        for (ll j = 0; j <= sqrtN; j++) {
            ll q = (i*i)+(j*j);
            if ((q < N) && isprime[q] && !zprime[q]) {
                zprimes.push_back(q);
                zprime[q] = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
int main(){
   calcprime();
   zcalc();
   cout << zprimes.size();
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The value of `q` can exceed the value of `N` in your code and can cause a segmentation fault when `zprime[q]`,`isprime[q]` is accessed. You're iterating `i`, `j` till `sqrt(N)` and have allocated `zprime`,`isprime` with `N` booleans. The value of q can vary from `0` to `2N`.

```
ll q = (i*i)+(j*j);
```

You can replace `bool zprime[N] = {};` and `bool isprime[N] = {};` with

```
bool zprime[N * 2 + 1] = {};
```

and

```
bool isprime[N * 2 + 1] = {};
```

respectively.

The program will no longer segfault. Or, you could check for `q < N` before accessing `isprime[q]` and `zprime[q]`.

Also, as has already been pointed out in the comments, `(i*i)+(j*j)` is an `int`. It is useless to assign that value to a `long long`. If you intend to prevent overflow, replace it with `((ll)i*i)+(j*j)`.

Moreover, for large sized arrays, you should prefer to allocate it on the heap.